# comparing some values at the table

Tags: sql, group-by, compare

| empno | ename | job | mgr | hiredate | sal | deptno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7839 | KING | PRESIDENT |  | 2031-11-17 | 5000.00 | 10 |
| 7934 | MILLER | CLERK | 7782 | 2032-01-23 | 1300.00 | 10 |
| 7782 | CLARK | MANAGER | 7839 | 2031-06-09 | 2450.00 | 10 |
| 7369 | SMITH | CLERK | 7902 | 2030-12-17 | 800.00 | 20 |
| 7876 | ADAMS | CLERK | 7788 | 2037-05-23 | 1100.00 | 20 |
| 7566 | JONES | MANAGER | 7839 | 2031-04-02 | 2975.00 | 20 |
| 7902 | FORD | ANALYST | 7566 | 2031-12-03 | 3000.00 | 20 |
| 7788 | SCOTT | ANALYST | 7566 | 2037-04-19 | 2900.00 | 20 |
| 7521 | WARD | SALESMAN | 7698 | 2031-02-22 | 1250.00 | 30 |
| 7844 | TURNER | SALESMAN | 7698 | 2031-09-08 | 1500.00 | 30 |
| 7900 | JAMES | CLERK | 7698 | 2031-12-03 | 950.00 | 30 |
| 7499 | ALLEN | SALESMAN | 7698 | 2031-02-20 | 1600.00 | 30 |
| 7698 | BLAKE | MANAGER | 7839 | 2031-05-01 | 2850.00 | 30 |
| 7654 | MARTIN | SALESMAN | 7698 | 2031-09-28 | 1250.00 | 30 |

so i have this table about that have data of the employee. what i want to ask is how to get someone who has bigger sal than the lowest sal manager that has the same deptno with him/her. and the job is not president or manager.

for example at the deptno number 20 the lowest sal manager is supposed to be jones with 2975. the one who has bigger sal than jones and have the same deptno with jones is ford so i want to print this out.
i already made my sql and i write it like this

```
select ename,sal from emp

where sal >= all(select min(sal) from emp where job = 'MANAGER' group by deptno)

and job not like 'PRESIDENT'

and job not like 'MANAGER'

group by deptno, ename,sal;
```

actually this kind of sql is work pretty well and can print ford out but when i look it again i notice that when i used all it just compare with all the data that took out with the where clause and not compare it by group by deptno number.
is there any way to compare the data group by deptno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a WHERE condition, `e1.deptno = e2.deptno`, that connects your sub query with the table.

```sql
SELECT e1.ename, e1.sal
FROM emp e1
WHERE sal >= (SELECT min(sal) FROM emp e2 WHERE e2.job = 'MANAGER' and e1.deptno = e2.deptno)
AND e1.job not like 'PRESIDENT'
AND e1.job not like 'MANAGER'
GROUP BY e1.deptno, e1.ename, e1.sal;
```

Kindly accept my answer if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a way to do this. Notice that slightly modified your query into a join instead of subquery

```
select e1.*
from emp e1
join 
(select deptno, min(sal) as minsal from emp where job = 'MANAGER' group by deptno) e
on e1.sal>=e.minsal and e1.deptno=e.deptno
AND e1.job not like 'PRESIDENT'
AND e1.job not like 'MANAGER'
```